# Invalid characters in file or folder names or invalid file types in OneDrive for Business

Tags: onedrive

I want to redirect my profile folder (Docs/Pics/Desktop) to my OneDrive for Business folder.

I have Visual Studio installed, so I have folders I cannot change with names containing  the `#` character, like

```
C:\Users\MyName\OneDrive - MyCompany\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Code Snippets\Visual C#
```

OneDrive for Business [does not support](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Invalid-characters-in-file-or-folder-names-or-invalid-file-types-in-OneDrive-for-Business-64883a5d-228e-48f5-b3d2-eb39e07630fa) folders with `#` in the name.

It appears that OneDrive Personal [is able to do selective sync](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/onedrive-selective-sync-windows-10), but it doesn't seem to be an option for OneDrive for Business.

I thought about changing folder visibility or permissions, but I don't want to break Visual Studio.

Anyone been here before?

Comment: Sorry - no onedrive-for-business tag

Comment: "I've been asked by my IT department" - ask your IT department to sort it out.

Answer (score 1):

Selective sync is now available on OneDrive for Business via the Settings>Account menu.

This will enable you to selectively remove some folders you don't want to sync and prevent the error messages syncing C# folders.

However, I found with my installation (Visual Studio 2017 and SQL Server Data Tools 2015) that there were some issues removing the folders from the selective sync menu. 
An additional option is to repoint the User Project Template and User Item Template folders to a different location on your computer outside of your OneDrive synced location.

This can be carried out in Visual Studio 2015 and 2017 through the Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Locations option.

You'll need to copy across any existing templates to the new location once you've repointed the folder location. The templates will then be available after a restart of Visual Studio.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-locate-and-organize-project-and-item-templates

The downside of this approach is that your templates won't be synced automatically to OneDrive, and it will depend on what access you have to create folders on your work PC.